# Tensorflow: 'Error: No gradients provided for any variable' with custom loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient-descent, backpropagation

I'm getting an error when I try to run my code

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable
```

Here's what my code looks like

```
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-2)

while True:
    #...other stuff

    if(isTimeToBackprop()):
         vStates = model.predict(modelInput)
         tdTargets = tf.ones(vStates.shape)

         loss = tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.math.squared_difference(vStates, tdTargets))

         callable = lambda : criticLoss
         optimizer.minimize(callable, var_list=model.trainable_variables)
```

All variables involved are of the type

```
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>
```

What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you are working with Tensorflow 2.x, If you are trying to create a custom training step, to track the model gradients, you have to invoke the model under the `tf.GradientTape` context manager.

Here you have your code updated to correctly work with the `GradientTape`:

```py
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-2)

while True:
    #...other stuff

    if isTimeToBackprop():
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            vStates = model(modelInput)
            tdTargets = tf.ones(vStates.shape)
            loss = tf.math.squared_difference(vStates, tdTargets)
            loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss)
        
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_weights))
        # At this point the model is updated
```

Also note that instead of using model.predict I am using the **call** method which is the one you should be using when training

Comment: Ah thank you! If I wanted a second model to be used, would I wrap that in the same GradientTape block or would that need to be in a second block?